# Keybindings in JtextArea to get typed text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener, key-bindings

Is there any way using **keybindings** in java to get the text i type in **JTextArea** 
in a string variable??

e.g If i type "Stack overflow" in **JtextArea** , using keybindings i need to get "stack overflow" in a string variable.

I can able to do it using keyListeners(by keypressed event) how can i achieve it in keybindings?

i have implemented keybindings for some keys , so what ever keys other than the specified keys are pressed it should be appended to a variable.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) is what you are looking for or possibly just a `DocumentFilter` to filter the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way using keybindings in java to get the text i type in
>   JTextArea in a string variable??
>
> e.g If i type "Stack overflow" in JtextArea , using keybindings i need
>   to get "stack overflow" in a string variable.
>
> I can able to do it using keyListeners(by keypressed event) how can i
>   achieve it in keybindings?

- use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
- [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) are designated for Keys commands/short_cuts, output from KeyBindings should be  [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) / [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), not to fills some variable

Comment: This worked i can able to get the length of document whenever a character is inserted. Is there any way i can get which key is pressed using documentlistener??

Comment: get which key is pressed using documentlistener?? = DocumentListener firing after any char is typed or char (sequence of chars) is inserted (and this isn't possible with KeyListener)